# How does DSL extension in Jenkins plugin work

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I want to create DSL extension for my Jenkins plugin (built using maven) just like in the example of Docker plugin for Jenkins. I see that the groovy file Docker.groovy is in: src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/Docker.groovy

Does this groovy file have to be within org.jenkinsci.plugin.docker.workflow, or can I just put it inside resources? What is the difference?

Also, If I define my DSL extension within the groovy file in this manner is the DSL extension available to call implicitly in the pipeline file?

Answer (score 4):

In order to make a step available in the Pipeline DSL through your plugin, you need to define a subclass of [Step](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-step-api/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/Step.html) that performs the needed task. This can be completely done within Java, and is the preferred method for adding expanding the Pipeline DSL within a Jenkins plugin.

The Docker example you linked is unusual in this instance, and doesn't define a typical Pipeline DSL step (the `docker` directive in Pipeline functions like a cross between an `agent`, a `step` and a `context` block). Furthermore, it appears to include a Java class that [loads the Groovy script dynamically](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-workflow-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/docker/workflow/DockerDSL.java%20%22%22), which acts as the entry point into the directive.

Groovy can be used to expand the Pipeline DSL; however this is done within the context of a [shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/), which is meant to be more of a boilerplate reducing tool to be used internally.